# Downloading PDF's using PDFkit error on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

I am trying to download an HTML view in Rails5 as a PDF, however, whenever I download the PDF I get an error: Failed to load PDF document. I am using the following gems:

gem 'pdf kit'
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary'

here is my controller:

```
class InputController < ApplicationController

def index
    @inputs = Input.all
end


def show
    @input = Input.find_by(id: params[:id])

            send_data @pdf, :filename => @input.company + ".pdf",
                                    :type => "application/pdf",
                                    :disposition => "attachment"
end


end
```

when i type in a download URL ie: localhost:3000/input/1.pdf i get a downloaded pdf file with an error:

[image]

My show view is very simple:

```
<ul>
<li><%= @input.company %></li>
<li><%= @input.position %></li>
<li><%= @input.date %></li>
</ul>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Best,
Ayaz

**UPDATE**

I also just tried taking out @pdf and putting in @input:

```
    def show
    @input = Input.find_by(id: params[:id])
            send_data @input, :filename => @input.company + ".pdf",
                                    :type => "application/pdf",
                                    :disposition => "attachment"
    end
```

No change in results

Comment: After the `@input =` line, write `p "--->#{@input}<---"`, and check your server window for what's between the two arrows.

Comment: i get the object: "--->#<Input:0x007fcbb8cce0d0><---". i did p "--->#{@input.company}<---" and i got the correct response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code doesn't assign anything to the instance variable `@pdf`:

```
def show
  @input = Input.find_by(id: params[:id])

  send_data @pdf, :filename => @input.company + ".pdf",
                  :type => "application/pdf",
                  :disposition => "attachment"
end
```

and instance variables have a default value of `nil`.  You need to do something like:

```
input = Input.find_by(id: params[:id])

html = %Q{
<ul>
<li>#{input.company}</li>
<li>#{input.position}</li>
<li>#{input.date}</li>
</ul>
}

kit = PDFKit.new(html, :page_size => 'Letter')
pdf = kit.to_pdf


send_data pdf, :filename => input.company + ".pdf",
               :type => "application/pdf",
               :disposition => "attachment"
```

Or, if you want to read the view file then run it through the ERB engine, something like this:

```
file_path = File.expand_path("../views/input/show.html.erb", __FILE__)
erb_template = File.read(file_path)

@input = Input.find_by(id: params[:id])
renderer = ERB.new(erb_template)
html = renderer.result()

#As above...
```

From the [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-by-default-convention-over-configuration-in-action):

> By default, controllers in Rails automatically render views with names
>   that correspond to valid routes.
>   ...
>   ...
>   The rule is that if you do not explicitly render something at the end
>   of a controller action, Rails will automatically look for the
>   action_name.html.erb template in the controller's view path and render
>   it.

And from the docs for [send_data()](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/DataStreaming/send_data):

> This method is similar to `render plain: data`, but also allows you to
>   specify whether the browser should display the response as a file
>   attachment (i.e. in a download dialog) or as inline data

Therefore, when you call `send_data()` in the controller, you are explicitly rendering something, so the default rendering of the action_name.html.erb file doesn't occur.

Comment: @AyazUddin, See my additions.

Comment: @AyazUddin As far as I can tell, `send_data()` interrupts the normal sequence of events, i.e. normally the action executes, then the corresponding view is rendered and sent to the browser.  `send_data()` tells rails not to render the corresponding view.

Comment: @AyazUddin, I added some quotes from the rails docs that explain what gets sent back to the browser.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help! Everything is working now. The information you sent over is very helpful!